# Node js push is not working, when adding a cart in case of existing user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am pushing a product to the cart. If the user exists then I want to push the product object to the array. But it is not working.

***Cart Router***

```
  router.post('/cart', checkJwt, (req, res, next) => {
        const product_id = req.query.productId;
        const quantity = req.query.quantity;
        const user = req.user.id;

      Cart.find({ user: req.user.id}, (err, existUser) => {
          if(err) next(err);
          if(existUser.length >= 1) {

            let cart = new Cart();
            cart.task_items.push({
              'task_item': product_id,
              'quantity': quantity
            })

            cart.save();
            res.json({
              msg: 'User exits exists',
              data: cart
            });

          } else {

            Cart.create({
              user,
              task_items: [{ product_id, quantity }]
            }, (err, carAdded) => {
              res.json({
                msg: 'User not exists',
                cart: carAdded
              });
            })
          }
        });

      });
```

***Cart Schema***

```
const monngose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = monngose.Schema;
const CartSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    task_items: [{
        task_item: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubTaskCategoryItem'},
        quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 }

    }],
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number
    },
    crreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = monngose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

In the database, I am getting a new record instead of pushing the object product. Node js push is not working, when adding a cart in case of the existing user.

Comment: In your Cart Router, why are you creating a new Cart object to push cart items into? Why not push into the same Cart object stored in ```existUser``` ?

Comment: Yes, but I am getting this error TypeError: **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**     existUser.task_items.push({
                task_item: product_id,
                quantity: quantity
            })

            existUser.save();

Comment: existUser will be an array since you have used Find method

Comment: Then what I need to do @VedantBang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first element of the `existUser` array (Its an array because you are using the find method), and push relevant data:

```js
existUser[0].task_items.push(...);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: :) If you don't please give an idea about, How to calculate the total price in cart?

Comment: Well I can't figure out that since I'll have to know your code better. I'd suggest you to try it on your own first, then ask another question if you can't get it done.

Comment: It's okay, I am trying by myself If there will be a problem I will post that.